# Why R+W > RF means immediate consistency?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, consistency

I'm trying to explain this to myself ..

Here's how I understand it :

Suppose I have 4 nodes, RF = 3 and CL = QUORUM for both read & write.

In my table (id, title) I write data {id = 1, title = 'mytext'} then write will return success if 2 nodes write this successfully. Say it's successfull, we now have (at least) 2 nodes with {id = 1, title = 'mytext'} and potentially one node with (id = 1, title = 'olddata')

Then any subsequent read (where id = 1) needs to find 2 nodes (QUORUM) with same data in order to return successfully which will never occur with the old data. because there's a maximum of 1 node remaining containing the old data.

Is that accurate?

Comment: You have data in 3 nodes. 2 with new and 1 with old. Reads wait for reply from any of the 2 of 3 nodes. 
- If 2 new data nodes, we are all good by getting latest data. 
- If 1 new data node and one old data node, new data will be chosen as read repair happens with the help of vector clock versions. 

So, we always would get latest data here.

Answer (score 0):

Number of nodes is not that important, more important is the RF i.e. how many nodes have the copy of the data. So CL Quorum means:

2 nodes have to confirm it on write
2 nodes have to confirm it on read

Under the hood the request will not actually go to all of the nodes. Based on some statistics, and the component snitch the coordinator will choose one of the nodes that have the data and the other nodes will just be asked for a hash, not the whole data. If the received data matches hash wise, then it's returned to the client. If not, coordinator will request the full data from the other nodes and resolve conflict by using last write wins policy.

In order to be able to do this, clocks have to be in sync. Usually by the ntp ... but some guys go even as far as installing GPS receivers on hosts to keep the clock skew really tight.

In short your reasoning is totally o.k.

And if you want to learn a bit more about all the combination it doesn't hurt to look at the following link:
https://www.ecyrd.com/cassandracalculator/

Comment: Thanks so much for your time! Makes it all very clear!